# Pandas - define pandas functions, pandas classes or write it like SQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have been thinking what the best way is to use pandas in Python. Whether that is to define small functions, a class, or just write entire pandas code in SQL-syntax-style? With SQL-syntax I mean just write everything line by line and execute the code until you get the dataframe you need to process.

So for example:

```
1. df['split_string'] = df['string'].str.split()

2. def split_strings(dataframe, s):
       dataframe['split_string'] = dataframe[s].str.split()
       return dataframe['split_string']

3. class splitAllStrings:
       def __init__(self, dataframe, s):
           self.dataframe = dataframe
           self.s = s
       
       def split_string(self):
           self.dataframe['string_split'] = self.dataframe[self.s].str.split()
           return self.dataframe['string_split']

3.1 split_s = splitAllStrings(df, column_to_split)
3.2 split_s.split_string()
```

So for software development, with a heavy use of Pandas, what is the best approach for maintainability? Moreover, are there any resources that teach how to build maintainable code with Python - preferably Pandas included?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application and taste. In notebooks we usually end up with imperative line-by-line commands. Any time you feel like repeating, it makes sense to create functions.

Pandas encourages chaining. `pipe`, `pd.DataFrame.assign`, `pd.DataFrame.query`, and `apply` are crucial for long chains of transformation.